# Most efficient way to write the code below in R

Tags: r, performance, copy

Using R, I want to paste the values from certain rows (1:58) from column 1 into the first 58 rows from another column. I want to repeat this 28 times in the most efficient way. Can anyone help?

This is what I have in mind but I want to do it more efficiently:

```
new_alpha_DNA$Alpha_Diversity[1:58] <- paste (new_alpha_DNA [1:58,1])
new_alpha_DNA$Alpha_Diversity[59:117] <- paste (new_alpha_DNA [1:58,2])
new_alpha_DNA$Alpha_Diversity[118:176] <- paste (new_alpha_DNA [1:58,3])
```

.... 28 times

Answer (score 2):

If they are of the same dimensions, we may subset the first 58 rows and the first 28 columns, `unlist` and just assign it to `Alpha_Diversity` in `new_alpha_DNA`

```
new_alpha_DNA$Alpha_Diversity <- unlist(new_alpha_DNA[1:58, 1:28])
```